# PNP-transistor collector connected to the output of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, pnp

Why is the transistor Q1 used in this configuration: collector is connected to the output of the op-amp U2? How does it work? I'm used to seeing that the output of the op-amp drives the base of the transistor. So I'm confused.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, Q1 is a constant current source of about 0.7V/2.5k = 160uA.

U2 is used as a comparator. When its output is low, it sources 160uA from Q1 via D6.

When its output transitions low to high, C2 will charge linearly at a rate determined by its value of 200pF and the 160uA it gets from Q1.

This will cause U1 output to go high to low when its input goes past the threshold.

In other words it's a delay circuit, with delay determined by the threshold voltage of U1 and the charge rate of C2.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 is a "current" generator charging C2,
excepted the case when output of U2 is driving "low" through D6 the collector of Q1.
This is the case of a "reset" of the charge of the capacitor C2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an op-amp, it's a comparator.

Comparators typically have open-drain/open-collector outputs, but this is an exception and has push-pull output.

The diode prevents the comparator to simply push the  logic gate input directly.

So there needs to be some kind of external circuit to pull the node high.

A simple resistor could be used, but in this circuit there needs to be a guarantee for a certain length pulse.

There is a capacitor which is charged with a transistor circuit which is a simple constant current source.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, the datasheet says that MAX987 has a push-pull output stage and can sink current. Does the diode D6 prevents the current from flowing when the output of the op-amp is high?

Comment: @dahaha yes it does. I will also fix the push-pull vs open-drain error.